# No puedo mergear rama de nuevo con git tras descartar commit

Tags: git, github

Hice un `merge` de una rama a master y tiempo después me di cuenta que esta rama tenía cambios que no quería.

He descartado el commit de ese `merge` con:

```
git revert -m 1 commit_hash
```

Ahora necesito volver a mergear de nuevo esa rama a master y no me deja. Parece como si ya estuviese mergeada, pero los cambios no aparecen en master. Me indica el mensaje: "`Already up-to-date.`" al intentar hacer merge de nuevo.

¿Alquien sabe qué está pasando? ¿Cómo puedo mergear esa rama de nuevo?

Edito:

- En la rama master, posteriormente a esto se han hecho algunos commits más
- En mi rama (en la que tengo el problema al hacer merge) no se ha hecho ningún commit ni cambio nuevo

Comment: prueba con un git log --graph para ver el arbol de ramas, o con otra herramienta grafica. Me parece que como tal la rama master continua con los cambios que hiciste. Yo suelo utilizar gitg y selecciono todas las ramas

Comment: No tiene los cambios, ya que actualizo y no aparecen los que estaban en esa rama y sin embargo si ha hecho revert: Revert "Merge branch "Nombre_de_mi_rama'". Es como que al descartar ese merge no dejase volver a hacerlo

Comment: añade una captura para ver como van tus ramas. Asi sin el grafico es un poco dificil ver el problema

Comment: Creo que tendrías que moverte a la rama no master, añadir los cambios y hacerlos efectivos (git add y git commit). Una vez hecho eso moviéndote a la rama master con un git checkout master y haciendo un merge con la rama creo que solucionaría tu problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El `revert` de un merge es confuso, porque no hace exactamente lo que piensas.

Si tienes esta historia:

```
                 H
--o--o--o--M--o--o
          /
   ---A--B
```

Donde `H` es *HEAD* (digamos por ejemplo de la rama master) y `M` es el commit en que hiciste merge, y en esa situación haces un `git revert -m1 M`, no se deshace el merge como si nunca se hubiera hecho, sino que se añade un nuevo commit a la rama master, pero un commit cuyos cambios son los contrarios de los que introdujo `M`. Llamémosle `W`

```
                    H
--o--o--o--M--o--o--W
          /
   ---A--B
```

Es decir, si por ejemplo, como consecuencia del merge `M` un archivo tiene un par de líneas añadidas, como consecuencia del revert `W` ese par de líneas serán borradas.

Dicho de otra forma, el commit `W` **introduce cambios** en tu historia, pero son cambios tales que todos tus ficheros quedan en un estado idéntico al que tenían en el commit anterior al `M`, más los cambios introducidos por los commits posteriores al `M`. Equivalente a editar tú mismo a mano esos ficheros, coregir los cambios que se habían introducido en el merge, y después hacer un `add` y un `commit` de esas modificaciones. Cambian los ficheros, pero no cambia la historia del grafo, donde podemos ver que el merge sigue estando ahi (y por tanto no puedes volver a hacerlo).

Dependiendo de qué haya ocurrido a partir del punto que muestro en la figura anterior (¿has seguido haciendo commits en la rama master? ¿Has seguido haciendo commits en la rama donde estaban `A` y `B`?) la solución para arreglar el desaguisado puede ser diferente.

Puedes leer más detalles (del propio Linus Torwalds) aquí: [How to revert a faulty merge](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) (de donde he "plagiado" las figuras). O editar tu pregunta para añadir información extra que me permita ayudarte.

**Actualización**

El usuario confirma que la rama original (`---A--B` en la figura) no ha tenido cambios, pero sí la rama máster. La situación actual entiendo que sería algo como esto:

```
                          H
--o--o--o--M--o--o--W--x--x
          /
   ---A--B
```

donde `x` serían los nuevos *commits* en master.

Cabe suponer que estos `x` han arreglado de alguna forma el problema que impedía que el merge en `M` no fuese válido, por lo que queremos hacer de nuevo aquel merge, pero no podemos porque ya está hecho.

Una solución es hacer un *revert* del commit que había hecho el *revert*. Puede sonar a trabalenguas, pero la idea es:

```
git revert W
```

y la cosa quedaría ahora:

```
                             H
--o--o--o--M--o--o--W--x--x--N
          /
   ---A--B
```

Con lo que los cambios que introdujo el commit `W` se aplican "al revés" en el commit `N`. Así, siguiendo el ejemplo antes mencionado, si el merge `M` había causado dos líneas nuevas en un fichero, en el primer revert `W` al fichero se le borraban esas dos líneas y este nuevo revert (`N`) añadirá de nuevo esas dos líneas al fichero.

Naturalmente esto puede causar conflicto si los ficheros "restaurados" en `W` han sido modificados de forma incompatible en alguno de los `x`, pero esto es algo que se resuelve en la forma conocida (se editan los ficheros en conflicto, se añaden con `git add` y se completa el revert con `git commit`)

Comment: entonces quizas lo que deberia haber hecho es un git reset --hard commit_hash no?

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación. he editado la pregunta respondiendo a tus cuestiones. Agradezco cualquier tipo de solución e información

Comment: @Norak He leido tu edición pero hay algo que no tengo aún claro. Cuando hiciste el merge ¿era de otra rama hacia tu master, o era de tu master hacia otra rama? (mis figuras reflejan el primer caso, pero al releerte me da la impresión de que fue el segundo)

Comment: @Jakala Se podría haber hecho eso, sí. Dependiendo de qué quisiera hacer exactamente y de sí ya había hecho push hacia un repositorio compartido (en cuyo caso la historia no debería modificarse)

Comment: @abulafia si, perdona que a lo mejor no lo dejé muy claro. El merge fue de mi rama hacia master. Es decir, situada en master: git merge <mi_rama> Gracias!

Comment: @abulafia eran unos cambios nuevo que pensaba incluir, después se decidió que no y deshice el merge. Pero finalmente se volvió a decidir que si. Sé que no es muy usual estos desacuerdos jeje. Pero creí que una vez descartado se podría volver a hacer pero me surgió este problema. Y si, yo creo que se corresponde con lo de tu figura, A y B

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @abulafia! Me has resuelto el problema y la explicación muy completa :)